# JSON format strings in a .TXT file that I want to parse in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, twitter, tweets

I am currently extracting Tweets from Twitter using Twitter IDs. The tool I am using comes with the dataset (Twitter IDs) that I have downloaded online and will be using for my masters dissertation. The tool takes the Twitter IDs and extracts the information from the Tweets, storing each Tweet as a JSON string in a .TXT file.

Below is a link to my OneDrive, where I have 2 files:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!At39YLF-U90fhJwCdEuzAc2CGLC_fg

1) Extracted Tweet information, each as a JSON string in a .txt file
2) Extracted Tweet information, each as a JSON string in what I believe is a .json file. The reason I say 'believe' is because the tool I am using automatically creates a file that contains '.json' at the end of the filename but in a .TXT format. I have simply renamed the file by removing 'TXT.' from the end

Below is code I have written (it is simple but the more I look for alternative code online, the more confused I become):

```
import pandas as pd
dftest = pd.read_json('test.json', lines=True)
```

The following error appears when I run the code:

*ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)*

I have run the first few Tweet arrays into a free online JSON parser and it breaks out the features of the Tweet exactly how I am wishing it to (to my knowledge this confirms they Tweet arrays are in a JSON format). This can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of online parser]

I would be grateful if people could:

1) Confirm the extracted Tweets are in fact in a JSON string format
2) Confirm if the filename is *automatically* saved as 'text.json.txt' and I remove 'txt' from the filename, does this become a .json file?
3) Suggest how to get my very short Python script to work. The ultimate aim is to identify the features in each Tweet that I want (e.g. "created_at", "text", "hashtags", "location" etc.) in a Dataframe, so I can then save it to a .csv file.

Comment: I think the problem is the `"` character at the start and end of each line - removing these may solve your problem. You might be able to use `strip('"')` on each line to remove these

Comment: Another issue is double quotation marks `""` throughout the document where there should be single quotation marks `"`

It may be easier to perform some pre-processing on this file in another tool to remove the leading & trailing `"` and replace all the `""` with `"`. On linux, a tool like `sed` could be used for this

Comment: Thanks Johnathon. I am running Mac OS, so the linux solution is not possible. I will look into your suggestion if there is nothing suggested that can directly resolve my issues, that doesn't involve amending the files (there are over 150, which makes it very time consuming). I'm also a little confused why the strings are immediately parsed when I use the free website. If they are in an incorrect format, wouldn't this fail?

I would also be grateful if people could explain whether deleting the '.txt' at the end of the filename, so it then ends with '.json' actually makes it a .json file?

Comment: `sed` should also be available on Mac

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. Are you able to advise on my question about whether the .txt files become .json files if I remove the .txt extension (examples in the link provided in the original question)?